# I'm trying to update a column of a table by adding some values but it does not get updated

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I created a table named emp and wanted to update values of the column ESAL by adding some values to each data but after executing the update query it doesn't get updated.

update emp set ESAL=ESAL+20 where ESAL<10000;[CODE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lsZV.png)

Comment: How could it be updated, when there's no ESAL < 10000? No rows satisfy WHERE condition and - consequentially - no rows were updated.

Comment: Please see the screenshot of my code where you will get more clearity.

Comment: I know, @Barbaros. I posted the way (one way?) that makes that possible, but - no response yet.

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow so I don't know to to write the way you wrote. So i'll upload screenshot of the entire code instead.

Comment: According to your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XBKZ.png) column ESAL is **float(5)**. For some reason it is not correctly updated (I don't not why), but same update works on number columns: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eW-xKq0o). Also select ESAL + 20 shows correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there, by any chance, a **trigger** on that table? Something which won't let `esal` to be updated?

```
SQL> create table temp (eno number, esal number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_emp
  2    before insert or update on temp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.esal := nvl(:old.esal, :new.esal);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into temp (eno, esal) values (1, 5000);

1 row created.

SQL> update temp set esal = esal + 20 where esal < 10000;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from temp;

       ENO       ESAL
---------- ----------
         1       5000

SQL>
```

What does this return in your database?

```
SQL> select trigger_name, trigger_type
  2  from user_Triggers
  3  where table_name = 'TEMP';                 --> you'd put EMP here

TRIGGER_NAME                   TRIGGER_TYPE
------------------------------ ----------------
TRG_BIU_EMP                    BEFORE EACH ROW

SQL>
```

---

You commented that there's no trigger.

Without it, table gets updated (at least, in my case):

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> drop trigger trg_biu_emp;

Trigger dropped.

SQL> select * from temp;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into temp (eno, esal) values (1, 5000);

1 row created.

SQL> update temp set esal = esal + 20 where esal < 10000;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from temp;

       ENO       ESAL
---------- ----------
         1       5020            --> 5020, as expected

SQL>
```

Comment: After running above code I got "no rows selected" in return

Comment: You mean, there's no trigger? Hm, that's kind of strange. See edited answer which shows that UPDATE works as expected. Could you start over and post everything from scratch, just like I did? From CREATE TABLE over INSERT to UPDATE and SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XBKZ.png)
I have done exactly the same thing which you did still the values are unaffected.

Comment: You shouldn't post an *answer*; that belongs to either a comment, or you should edit original question. Anyway: that screenshot does NOT look like what I did.  First of all, you're running it under SYSTEM account - that's simply wrong. Leave SYS and SYSTEM alone; they are *special*, own the database and shouldn't be used for anything but system maintenance. Furthermore, if you paid attention, I started with CREATE TABLE, while your code begins with SELECT FROM EMP - that's not the same. I'd suggest you to create new user and start over. Then post what you did and how Oracle responded.